# CSS Grid image and column issue in Chrome

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

In Chrome, [my site](https://nissan-heritage.netlify.com/) is breaking on desktop and mobile.

Issues:

- The second section isn't displaying the hero image correctly. The image should have two halves that when hovered, join together.
- Hero images jump to the top of the page with only half of the image in view.

  When I went to inspect the page, I saw the following in the console

> [Deprecation] Percentages row tracks and gutters for indefinite height grid containers will be resolved against the intrinsic height instead of being treated as auto and zero respectively

I looked into it and came to [find the fix](https://blogs.igalia.com/mrego/2018/08/10/changes-on-css-grid-layout-in-percentages-and-indefinite-height/) for the said issue was to change percentages in *grid-template-rows* or *grid-auto-rows* to *auto*.

I applied the given fix and the issue still persisted. It only breaks in Google Chrome. The site looks fine in Firefox.

[image]

[image]

Here's the code.

HTML:

```
        <section class="page">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Skyline KPGC110</h1>
            <h2>1973</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="hero">
            <a href="./kenmeri.html">
              <img class="model-left" src="./images/front-1.png" alt="model">
              <img class="model-right" src="./images/front-2.png" alt="model">
            </a>
          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- ------------------------------ Seciton 2 ------------------------------ -->

        <section class="page about">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Skyline PGC10</h1>
            <h2>1969</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="hero">
            <a href="./pgc10.html">
              <img class="model-left" src="./images/gtr-left.png" alt="chef">
              <img class="model-right" src="./images/gtr-right.png" alt="chef">
            </a>
          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- ------------------------------ Section 3 ------------------------------ -->

        <section class="page reel">
          <div class="details">
            <h1>Fairlady 240z</h1>
            <h2>1973</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="hero">
            <a href="./fairladyz.html">
              <img class="model-left" src="./images/240z-left.jpg" alt="model">
              <img class="model-right" src="./images/240z-right.jpg" alt="model">
            </a>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Desktop view:

```
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5% 1fr 1fr 1fr 5%;
  min-height: 90vh;
}

.about,
.reel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;  /*  gets rid of gap between imgs */
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hero a {
  display: flex; /* removes seperation created by a tag */
}

.hero img {
  height: 500px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Breakpoint 1(Laptop):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .page {
    grid-template-columns: 5% 1fr 5%;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .hero {
    height: auto;
    grid-column: 2;
  }

  .hero img {
    height: 425px;
  }
}
```

Breakpoint 2(Mobile):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .page {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }

  .page-1 h3 {
    font-size:  1.125rem;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }

  .hero img {
    width: auto;
  }

  .details h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}
```

The link to the repo is [here](https://github.com/dvlprdave/Nissan-Heritage) if you want to get a full look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%;
}
```

just remove the width: 100% and it will work fine.